# How to show more variables in modules

Tags: python

Im just starting to learn practice it however my problem I bet is easy to resolve I’m trying my best but my knowledge is too low to solve this out , I’ve try commas brackets but still didn’t work I just want to get print the name country and age , sorry for newbie question please help

Main.py

```
import one

a = one.person1["name"]
b = one.person2["name"]
c = one.person3["name"]


def input():
    print(one(name))
```

One.py

```
person1 = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": "6",
  "country": "Norway"
}
person2 = {
  "name": "Jn",
  "age": "36",
  "country": "Norway"
}
person3 = {
  "name": "krun",
  "age": "36",
  "country": "Norway"
}
```

Comment: `print( one.person1["name"], one.person1["age"], one.person1["country"]  )`

Comment: if you want to display for all person then keep them on list - i.e `persons = [...]` - and use `for`-loop

Comment: You will want to print your `a`, `b` and `c`, eg `print(a, b, c)`. To get country or age, fetch those values by their keys just like you did with the names. I strongly suggest you visiting a python tutorial program to consolidate some first steps on python such as these.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display one person then use every key separatelly

```
print( one.person1["name"], one.person1["age"], one.person1["country"] )
```

And then you can format output

```
print('name =', one.person1["name"])
print('age =', one.person1["age"])
print('country =', one.person1["country"])
```

You can also display directly `print(one.person1)` but then you can't format output.

---

If you want to display all persons then keep them on list and then you can use `for`-loop

```
persons = [one.person1, one.person2, one.person2]

for item in persons:
    print( item["name"], item["age"], item["country"]  )
```

If you don't know keys then you can use `.keys()` or `.items()` in dictionary

```
for item in persons:
    for key, value in item.items():
        print(key, '=', value)
```

---

if you want to get key from user then

```
key = input("what to show: ")

print(one.person1[key])
print(one.person2[key])
print(one.person3[key])
```

or better keep persons on list and use `for`-loop

```
key = input("what to show: ")

persons = [one.person1, one.person2, one.person2]

for item in persons:
    print( item[key] )
```

Comment: From ur answer it’s printing me single ones isn’t it , I want to have on input like I did for inputting A will give me this details for B ye other one for example

Comment: if you want for all persons then you have to repeate code for every person separatelly or keep all persons on list and use for-loop.

Comment: if you nead to get value from user then you have to use `key = input()` and `print(one.person1[key])` `print(one.person2[key])` `print(one.person3[key])` or put all persons on list to use `for`-loop

Comment: From all the answers it’s to show all lopped etc... my easy question was what should I add to this piece to make for B to show me persons2 name and country ? Or do I really have to write all this different way ?

Comment: import one

a = one.person1.get("name")
b = one.person2.get("country") 'and name for this one only how ? '
c = one.person3.get("name")


def input():
 print(one(x))

Comment: your idea is wrong. if you need `name` and `country` for `person2` then you have to get every item separatelly `name2 = one.person2["name"]` and `country2 = one.person2["country"]` or display `print(one.person2["name"], one.person2["country"])`. If you assign `b = one.person2` without `["name"]` or `.get("name")` then you can do `print(b["name"], b["country"])`.

Comment: Other problem is that `one` is name of module and you can't use it as function `one()`. Maybe you need `def input(x): print(x["name"]) and then you can run it as `input(one.person2)` or `input(b)` and function will do `x = one.person2` and later `x["name"]` will means `one.person2["name"]`

Comment: Thanks to you furas that’s what I wanted and it works ❤️

import one

a = one.person1.get("name")
b = (one.person2["name"], one.person2["country"])
c = one.person3.get("name")


def input():
 print(one(x))